# Vue and repeated props

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a series of components that represents different form field types. These are designed not to have any dependency on their parents so all their various attributes are passed in as individual props.

I'm trying to write a wrapper component for these fields that will handle some logic that is specific to my current implementation.

The idea is that I'll have a component called `mws-field` that will handle the additional logic and then output the required component based on its `type` prop.

However, this means mapping all the props from the parent component onto every child component. Currently my `mws-field` template looks like this:

```
<template>
    <form-field-select v-if="field && type == 'select'" 
        :label="label" 
        :classes="classes" 
        :placeholder="placeholder" 
        :tooltip="tooltip" 
        :domName="field.domName" 
        :required="field.required" 
        :value="field.value"
        :disabled="field.vm.disabled"
        :review="field.vm.review"
        :errors="field.errors"
        :options="options"
    ></form-field-select>

    <form-field-text v-else-if="field && type == 'text'" 
        :label="label" 
        :classes="classes" 
        :placeholder="placeholder" 
        :tooltip="tooltip" 
        :domName="field.domName" 
        :required="field.required" 
        :value="field.value"
        :disabled="field.vm.disabled"
        :review="field.vm.review"
        :errors="field.errors"
    ></form-field-text>

    ... etc

</template>
```

I've got more than a dozen of these components and in the majority of cases they share the same set of props.

I thought the answer was in the `render()` method but as I understand it, this would need the `functional` flag, which isn't supported in components.

Is there a less verbose, neater, more manageable way of doing this?

Comment: What about passing all of these in an object instead? You can simply put all these props into an object, and pass them into your component.

Comment: also, as of 11 hours ago, the [newest version of Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases) supports dynamic `type` on `input` elements. https://jsfiddle.net/w2x5em9z/

Comment: @thanksd, that's really good to know, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `v-bind` an object to specify the props you want to pass:

```
<template>
  <form-field-select v-if="field && type == 'select'" v-bind="inputProps"/>
  <form-field-text v-else-if="field && type == 'text'" v-bind="inputProps"/>
</template>
```

<!>

```
data() {
  return {
    inputProps: {
      label: this.label,
      classes: this.classes,
      placeholder: this.placeholder,
      tooltip: this.tooltip,
      domName: this.field.domName,
      required: this.field.required,
      value: this.field.value,
      disabled: this.field.vm.disabled,
      review: this.field.vm.review,
      errors: this.field.errors,
      options: this.options,
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's the documentation on `v-bind`.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

Comment: You beauty! Didn't realise I could pass v-bind an object like this, but it's exactly what I was after. Many thanks.